# Is it faster to compare strings with Regex with IgnoreCase or with ToLower method of string?

Tags: c#, regex

Given strings like these:

```
string s1 = "Abc";
string s2 = "ABC";
```

What is faster:

```
Regex.Match(s1, s2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

or

```
s1.ToLower() == s2.ToLower()
```

If they are the same or the one is faster then the other, so when its better to use one over the other?

Comment: Normal string operations are faster than regular expressions generally.

Comment: Regex.Match is highly incorrect. It is not a viable solution anyway. A regex is not a string - it is a regex pattern.

Comment: @fardjad, why regex generally slower?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably the second is faster, but I'd avoid both those approaches.

Better is to use the method [`string.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9) with the appropriate `StringComparison` argument:

```
s1.Equals(s2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/2mTc5)

Comment: +1, also consider the case where s2 is an invalid regular expression.

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically speaking, comparing 2 strings should be faster, RegEx are know to be rather slow.

However, if you want to match a string s1 to a RegEx s2 while ignoring case (This is not the same as comparing 2 strings), then the first solution is better as it should avoid creating another string.

As always with this kind of questions, I would run a benchmark and compare both performances :)

Comment: I would +1 for pointing out that a benchmark is the best way to answer these questions, but I am out of votes for today!

Answer (score 4):

@Mark Byers has already posted the right answer.

I want to stress that you should *never* use ToLower for string comparison. It is incorrect.

```
s1.Equals(s2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) //#1
s1.ToLower() == s2.ToLower() //#2
s1.ToLowerInvariant() == s2.ToLowerInvariant() //#3
```

(2) and (3) are both incorrect when it comes to exotic languages and strange characters. The Turkish "I" is the classical example.

**Always use #1**, even in Hashtables

*(except for very special circumstances)*

Answer (score 3):

It should be noted that `Regex.Match(s1, s2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)` is not a safe way to check for case-insensitive equality in the general case. Consider the case where `s2` is `".*"`. `Regex.Match` will always return true no matter what `s1` is!

Answer (score 3):

This may be the most extreme case of  [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) I've ever seen.  Trust me, you will never run into a situation where this issue will be relevant.

And don't listen to all those people who tell you to avoid regexes because "they're slow".  *Badly written* regexes can indeed hog resources something awful, but that's the fault of whoever wrote the regex.  Reasonably well-crafted regexes are plenty fast enough for the vast majority of tasks people apply them to.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing will be faster but Instead of converting to lower or upper case and then comparing, its better to use an equality comparison which can be made case-insensitive. E.g. :

```
        s1.Equals(s2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small comparison of the 3 methods proposed:

> Regex: 282ms 
>   ToLower: 67ms 
>   Equals: 34ms

```
public static void RunSnippet()
{
    string s1 = "Abc";
    string s2 = "ABC";

    // Preload
    compareUsingRegex(s1, s2);
    compareUsingToLower(s1, s2);
    compareUsingEquals(s1, s2);

    // Regex
    Stopwatch swRegex = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < 300000; i++) 
        compareUsingRegex(s1, s2);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Regex: {0} ms", swRegex.ElapsedMilliseconds));

    // ToLower
    Stopwatch swToLower = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < 300000; i++) 
        compareUsingToLower(s1, s2);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ToLower: {0} ms", swToLower.ElapsedMilliseconds));

    // ToLower
    Stopwatch swEquals = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < 300000; i++) 
        compareUsingEquals(s1, s2);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Equals: {0} ms", swEquals.ElapsedMilliseconds));
}

private static bool compareUsingRegex(string s1, string s2) 
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(s1, s2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}

private static bool compareUsingToLower(string s1, string s2) 
{
    return s1.ToLower() == s2.ToLower();
}

private static bool compareUsingEquals(string s1, string s2) 
{
    return s1.Equals(s2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: That's not a fair comparison.  I tried creating the Regex object ahead of time and storing it in a static variable, then calling `IsMatch()` on that, with this result: `Regex: 71ms`, `ToLower: 51 ms`, `Equals: 23 ms`.

Comment: It's also not a useful comparison because of the case where `s2` contains an actual regular expression.

Comment: Requirement was to make a string comparison with ignore case. You can of course make several optimizations if you say that s1 will never change (in this case you can compile/keep the regexp object)